# Globally Disable Microphone in Big Sur?

Tags: cpu, big-sur, microphone, privacy, speech

After upgrading to ***Big Sur*** from ***Catalina***, I remarked my fan was running continuously. Opening Activity Monitor I remarked that "***com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond***" was chewing through CPU at 37.3%.

Looking a likely candidate, and just being a bit anal about having a microphone in an ***always-on*** state, I wanted to knock that nonsense on the head.

There was a microphone graphic on my screen which presented the option to "***Sleep***" which when clicked then presented the option to toggle the mic to "***Wake Up***". Clicking this did nothing: Speech Recognition nonetheless kept the fan humming and chomping through CPU cycles.

[image: SpeechRecognition]

After toggling every application's access to the microphone to deny access, "***com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond***" was still happily chomping through CPU.

***Where is a setting to toggle the microphone off at OS level in Big Sur?!?!?!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drove me bananas. Should be straightforward, but it isn't.

Googling returned lots of results for disabling the microphone on an ***application-specific*** basis in Big Sur, but absolutely oogatz on a global toggle to kill the microphone on a ***GLOBAL*** basis to both stop Speech Recognition from chewing up my CPU as well as shut down an open mic.

I next visited "***System Preferences***" > "***Sound***" which ***seemed*** a logical place to tweak such a toggle. Nope.

It's actually buried in "***System Preferences***" > "***Accessibility***". No, I'm not joking; that's where it lives. Untick "***Enable Voice Control***" and if you go back to Activity Monitor, you'll see you get your CPU back and the microphone ***should*** be down.

[image: SysPrefAccessibility]

Another thing that really irks me is that Apple is supposed to telling you when something is accessing the microphone or camera, but you don't get a warning when Apple itself is triggering the microphone. ANYTHING that accesses the microphone or camera ***SHOULD*** trigger a warning light IMHO.

Comment: Yes unfortunately some settings are in accessibility which should appear in other places, like you can change some trackpad settings in `Accessibility` instead of in `Trackpad` settings. Also you can enable microphones, camera, speech recognition, disk access, bluetooth, etc. for specific apps in `Security & Privacy Settings`>`Privacy`.